# Analyzing Asp.net deadlock crash dump

Tags: asp.net, debugging, windbg, deadlock, adplus

I'm having a deadlock on my asp.net. I don't know where it comes from (what function), not talking about where in that function.

I generated dump file using adplus (http://support.microsoft.com/?ID=828222)

and then used Debug Diag & windbg to find the problem. ( no success yet.. :( )

I'm out of Ideas! Please help me...

(Windows 2003, Asp.net 2, 32Bit)

Windbg dump:

```
This dump file has a breakpoint exception stored in it.
The stored exception information can be accessed via .ecxr.
eax=7ffda000 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000002 edx=00000003 esi=00000004 edi=00000005
eip=7c81a251 esp=082affcc ebp=082afff4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0038  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c81a251 cc              int     3
0:032> .loadby sos mscorwks 
Unable to find module 'mscorwks '
0:032> .loadby sos mscorwks
0:032> .load C:\psscor2\x86\psscor2.dll
0:032> .load C:\psscor2\sosex.dll

0:032> kL

ChildEBP RetAddr  
082affc8 7c83fc40 ntdll!DbgBreakPoint
082afff4 00000000 ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin+0x36

0:032> !threads

ThreadCount: 23
UnstartedThread: 0
BackgroundThread: 17
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 6
Hosted Runtime: no
                                      PreEmptive   GC Alloc           Lock
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ    State     GC       Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
  12    1  a10 000d3a70   1808220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  14    2  a88 000eccf8      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Finalizer)
  15    3  bec 00105d58    80a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
  16    4  f04 00108cf0      1220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn
  18    5  dc0 0015c4b0   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  19    6  e24 0013a980   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  20    7  cc8 00178538   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  21    f  db0 0017ed58   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  10   11 1704 05a569a8   880a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
   6   12 172c 05a5c070       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn
   4   13   84 05a5af20       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn
   3   14  910 05a5ab50       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn
   5   15 1270 05a565d8       220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn
  22    b  8f8 0017be18   200b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 001093e0     1 MTA
  24   20 11cc 08143240   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  25   1b  ac4 080b3228   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
  26    8 1470 08039b90   180b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX    a    0 0808dc98   1801820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   1d    0 081cab88   1801820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   10    0 080686a0   1801820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   1c    0 08112bf8   1801820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   19    0 0af46a38   1801820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXXX   1f    0 0b1fa510      9820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 000e03f8     0 Ukn


0:032> ~22s

eax=02656ae8 ebx=059ee7e8 ecx=00000005 edx=00000538 esi=059ee7ec edi=7ffda000
eip=7c82847c esp=059ee79c ebp=059ee844 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
7c82847c c3              ret

0:022> kL

ChildEBP RetAddr  
059ee798 7c827b89 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
059ee79c 77e6202c ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
059ee844 79fccf6a kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a
059ee8ac 79fccb97 mscorwks!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x6f
059ee8cc 79fccca0 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x3c
059ee950 79fccd35 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c
059ee9a0 7a0da8eb mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
059eeadc 047cb3ff mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitMultipleNative+0x1ec
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for System.ni.dll
059eeb00 7a55fc89 mscorlib_ni+0x1cb3ff
059eeb54 04816e46 System_ni+0x11fc89
059eeb60 04835781 mscorlib_ni+0x216e46
059eeb70 79e71b4c mscorlib_ni+0x235781
059eeb80 79e896ce mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
059eec00 79e96ea9 mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
059eed44 79e96edc mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c
059eed60 79e96efa mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f
059eed78 79ef2bf9 mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::CallWithValueTypes+0x1a
059eef44 79ef2d4e mscorwks!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+0x9f
059eeff4 04835677 mscorwks!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x10f
059ef010 048202a5 mscorlib_ni+0x235677

0:022> !clrstack

OS Thread Id: 0x8f8 (22)
ESP       EIP     
059eea20 7c82847c [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 059eea20] System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean, Boolean)
059eeaec 047cb3ff System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean)
059eeb0c 7a55fc89 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()
059eeb5c 04816e46 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
059eeb68 04835781 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)
059eef98 79e71b4c [HelperMethodFrame_PROTECTOBJ: 059eef98] System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode, CleanupCode, System.Object)
059ef000 04835677 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
059ef01c 048202a5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
059ef034 04816dc4 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
059ef260 79e71b4c [GCFrame: 059ef260] 
059ef550 79e71b4c [ContextTransitionFrame: 059ef550] 

0:022> !mk

Thread 22:
     ESP      EIP
00:U 059ee79c 7c82847c ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
01:U 059ee7a0 7c827b89 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
02:U 059ee7a4 77e6202c kernel32!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x11a
03:U 059ee84c 79fccf6a mscorwks!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx_SO_TOLERANT+0x6f
04:U 059ee8b4 79fccb97 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateAptStateWait+0x3c
05:U 059ee8d4 79fccca0 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x13c
06:U 059ee958 79fccd35 mscorwks!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x40
07:U 059ee9a8 7a0da8eb mscorwks!WaitHandleNative::CorWaitMultipleNative+0x1ec
08:M 059eeae4 047cb3ff System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(System.Threading.WaitHandle[], Int32, Boolean)(+0x88 IL)(+0x8f Native)
09:M 059eeb08 7a55fc89 System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc()(+0x14d IL)(+0x2f9 Native)
0a:M 059eeb5c 04816e46 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)(+0xfffffffd IL)(+0x66 Native)
0b:M 059eeb68 04835781 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(System.Object)(+0x0 IL)(+0x51 Native)
0c:U 059eeb78 79e71b4c mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
0d:U 059eeb88 79e896ce mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
0e:U 059eec08 79e96ea9 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c
0f:U 059eed4c 79e96edc mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f
10:U 059eed68 79e96efa mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::CallWithValueTypes+0x1a
11:U 059eed80 79ef2bf9 mscorwks!ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanupHelper+0x9f
12:U 059eef4c 79ef2d4e mscorwks!ReflectionInvocation::ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup+0x10f
13:M 059eeffc 04835677 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)(+0xfffffffd IL)(+0x67 Native)
14:M 059ef018 048202a5 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)(+0xfffffffd IL)(+0x45 Native)
15:M 059ef030 04816dc4 System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()(+0xfffffffd IL)(+0x44 Native)
16:U 059ef048 79e71b4c mscorwks!CallDescrWorker+0x33
17:U 059ef058 79e896ce mscorwks!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa3
18:U 059ef0d8 79e96ea9 mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x19c
19:U 059ef214 79e96edc mscorwks!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x1f
1a:U 059ef230 79e96efa mscorwks!MethodDescCallSite::CallWithValueTypes+0x1a
1b:U 059ef248 79f88357 mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread_Worker+0x192
1c:U 059ef430 79e9cc8f mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x32a
1d:U 059ef444 79e9cc2b mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
1e:U 059ef4d8 79e9cb51 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
1f:U 059ef514 79eb392a mscorwks!Thread::RaiseCrossContextException+0x434
20:U 059ef524 79eb48b9 mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0xda
21:U 059ef5d4 79eb394b mscorwks!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x310
22:U 059ef5f0 79e9cc2b mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0xe3
23:U 059ef684 79e9cb51 mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x30a
24:U 059ef6c0 79e9ccdd mscorwks!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x33e
25:U 059ef6e8 79f88128 mscorwks!ManagedThreadBase::KickOff+0x13
26:U 059ef700 79f88202 mscorwks!ThreadNative::KickOffThread+0x269
27:U 059ef79c 79f0e255 mscorwks!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x49
28:U 059effc0 77e6482f kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34
```

Comment: Do you use MUTEX in your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for dead loops like redirect to the same page.

eg

```
Responce.Redirect("samepage.aspx");
```

or `Server.Transfer` to the same page, or something like

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // call by mistake the OnInit and make close loop
  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Or maybe something like this that calling him self and crash.

```
public string Text
{
   get {return Text;}
   set {Text = value;}
}
```

or screenscraping the same page.

Comment: I'm not using server.transfer or asp.net pages. Just ashx pages. My guess is that the problem occours somewhere inside a thread that I made but I really don't know

Comment: @Shay search as I say you for one of the above thinks. Look your code and see if there is any point that the same page call again and again their self.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through all managed threads and analyze all managed call stacks via !CLRStack? You must find out why each thread is waiting, and then locate the culprit.

If you still cannot find the cause, then you may open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and share the dumps with the support guys. They have the expertise to find out the possible causes.